# blank page shows up after adding \usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, blank-page

I have `index.tex` that I made a copy of it. renamed the copy to `index_bad.tex`, and added the line

```
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
```

to its preamble. So the 2 files are identical other than this one change.

Then compiled `index.tex` with `pdflatex` 3 time and looked at the index.pdf, and it is ok. (i.e. no blank page).

Compiled `index_bad.tex` with `pdflatex` 3 times. Now `index_bad.pdf` has an extra blank page inserted between first section and the second section.

This is the general layout of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=.7in,right=.5in,top=.7in,bottom=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
....
\section{....}
\subsection{...}
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,framesep=1mm,samepage=true,fontsize=\footnotesize]
.....
\begin{Verbatim}[frame=single,framesep=1mm,samepage=true,fontsize=\footnotesize]
....
\end{document}
```

When including `hyperref` a blank page shows up between first section, and the second section.  No blank page shows up when this package is not included.

**question is** why does this happen? and how to fix it?

Since this document includes 2 images and large verbatim, I've zipped the whole folder so it is all self contained.

Unziping the zip file will create a folder. Inside the folder there is `index.tex` and `index_bad.tex` and the 2 images used. Running `pdflatex` on the files will show the problem above.

The zip file is http://12000.org/tmp/072113/latex_problem.zip

Using TL 2013 on Linux mint virtual machine hosted on windows.

[image]

Comment: It is obvious that the `Verbatim` frames are too large, since they visibly overflow into the page footer. That's what it causing the blank page, most likely.

Comment: @Werner, But the question is, why the blank page does not show up when hyperref not included?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Werner has noticed, you have an overlarge page. TeX goes to the next page to set the oversized page, if the current page is *not* empty. That it, what happened here. The page is not empty, if package `hyperref` is loaded.

Package `hyperref` has to add anchors for the `\section` commands (otherwise the links would not have targets to jump to). It hooks into `\refstepcounter` for setting the anchor. Thus the example can be reduced to:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1

\begin{document}

Dummy page
\newpage  

\refstepcounter{section}% anchor setting with hyperref
\showlists
\rule{1pt}{1.1\textheight}

\end{document}
```

The `\rule` ensures that the page is overlarge:

```
Overfull \vbox (54.85335pt too high)
```

Without `hyperref` there are two pages and the page is empty after `\refstepcounter{section}`:

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
prevdepth 2.33331, prevgraf 1 line

! OK.
l.15 \showlists
```

With `hyperref` the result is three pages and the
page start after `\refstpecounter` is not empty and the anchor/link destination can be seen (driver `pdftex`):

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\pdfdest name{section.1} xyz

prevdepth 2.33331, prevgraf 1 line

! OK.
l.15 \showlists
```

Thus the only unhappiness is that the page is broken between the destination and the section title. Fixing this would mean more digging/messing with internals, causing other incompatibilities.

BTW, you get the same behavior with other "whatits", e.g. index commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\showboxdepth=\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth=\maxdimen
\tracingonline=1

\begin{document}

Dummy page
\newpage

\index{foo}
\showlists
\rule{1pt}{1.1\textheight}

\end{document}
```

Result three pages with:

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### recent contributions:
\write3{\indexentry{foo}{\thepage }}
prevdepth 2.33331, prevgraf 1 line

! OK.
l.16 \showlists
```

### Solution

The problem with the `overfull \vbox` needs to be resolved. A dirty way is:

```
\newpage
\enlargethispage{24.7852pt}
\section{Tikz solution}
```